# Sort jquery datatable column excluding first record

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I am using jquery dtatable.
On form load it display list of user. I want sorting on last name in ascending . and one admin user record must be at first place initial load.

I tried to set Last Name is ascending and TYPE in desc but admin goes at last row

```
"aaSorting": [[2,'asc']],
  "aoColumns": [ /*Member id*/  {sClass: "displayHide"},
 /*First Name*/  {sClass: "alignCenter "},
 /*Last Name*/  {sClass: "alignCenter "},     
 /*Type*/  {sClass: "alignCenter "},
```

Is it any jquery property available to keep admin record at first place.

**EDIT**

Added sample example

```
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME TYPE

p          m        Admin    
q          a        user
r          c        user
s          d        user
```

Only one record present for admin type. remaining are user type.
Admin must be at first place and remaining records are sorted by lastname.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of options.

1) Just use `"aaSortingFixed": [[3, 'asc']]` to lock down sorting by type first. Keep in mind that then the list is always sorted by Type first and then by lastname.

2) Have a hidden column (eg. is this row admin) and use `"aaSortingFixed"` to sort by that column.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a 'thead' element, this should prevent sorting of the top, same applies for the bottom row, wrapping it in a 'tfoot' element.